# Would it be possible to embed CDF files to posts?

Tags: feature-request, cdf

It would be nice to be able to manipulate dynamic content directly from the browser: everything is given on the *Mathematica*-side (CDF, deployment, browser-plugin), and the site would certainly benefit from it: imagine, that new users who just installed *Mathematica* but have no idea how to use it could immediately try out small programs without copypasting/evaluating them.
I realize that SE does not allow the attachment of files to posts (would be useful though in many cases). Perhaps this can be done sometimes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While I totally support the idea, I have very strong doubts this would ever be possible on SE. Just put yourself in place of SE developers / management: if I were one of them, here are some things that would be a complete no-go:

- Security: since this is based on a plugin, this can affect the client computer in a variety of ways, *and* SE has no control over it, while full responsibility for it.
- Dependency on external technology, over which SE has no control: the idea is that the posts can stay here for an indefinitely long time and be accessed by new users without problems. If there are some breaking changes introduced in future versions of CDF, this would make older posts broken

I am sure there are other considerations as well.

Comment: Then it is quite obvious that there should be a dedicated site for such things. Of course there is the Demonstrations site, but there you cannot post problems, and cannot have discussions. I am aware that there is a movement to set up a github repository, which is somewhat similar to this question in the sense that it looks for a way to have files on a server that many can access. Maybe there is a general solution for both of these?

Comment: @Istvan I have been thinking about this, but can not offer a fully staisfactory and general solution at the moment. Meanwhile, we can use GitHub for code, and some file-sharing service like 4shared for other files (they have a restriction that you have to visit your account once per half a year, but in the short-term this may be ok).